# Recover from Grub error

Tags: linux, boot, partition, grub

I  use windows as well as Linux in one laptop. I don't know what I deleted in the partition settings. Suddenly when I restarted my laptop, it showed me the below error message.

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
```

Then I tried many command keys from each partition, but it always blimps a error `unknown command` or `unknown file system`.

I don't have a cd drive to backup my laptop. But I have a pendrive installed with windows file and ubuntu 12.

Again I tried to recover it. But still the same and no changes.  How can I recover it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which distro of Linux you have installed, but I'll make a bad assumption here the since you have a flash drive with Ubuntu, you are running Ubuntu.

Also, make sure you have a back up. You can still get to your files by mounting the drive. I explain how to mount below, or you can look at man pages.

There is a program called [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Open up your ubuntu running on your flash drive and install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Then go through and set your settings and aim it at your drive. It will probably be `sda`, but you can look it up with `lsblk`. Then whichever partition table looks like what you remember is probably the drive.

If there is any question about what is in there, use (as an example) `sudo mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt` to mount it so you can take a look around. Then just `cd /mnt` to change directories to your mount point.